# How to Change URL from example.com/folder/file.php to example.com/name?

Tags: php, url, web

I recently bought a hosting plan and I am wondering how to do this basic thing.

How can I change the URL from `example.com/folder/file.php` to `example.com/name` or `example.com/file.php`?

Comment: There was no need to down-vote the question. You're supposed to help people who are new in this domain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using cPanel, you can open file manager, navigate to the folder `folder` then click on the `file.php` and drag it into the folder you want it.

If not cpanel, just move it to the folder through the same basic operation, it is a question of drag and drop!

Enjoy.

Comment: Thought there was another way. Thank you, though!